# The Canada tag should probably go

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Why is there even a [canada](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/canada) tag?  Isn't that a bit too localized?  I did a quick look, and there's no [usa](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/usa) or [great-britain](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/great-britain) or [australia](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/australia), so why on $DEITY'S green Earth is there a [canada](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/canada) tag?

There's 5 questions there, of which at least a couple I feel could be closed as too localized.  I just want to get people's opinion on it before doing anything.

Comment: Well, my personal life goal is to get the copper tag badge for Canada.  I take offense.

Comment: Offense taken on both sides sir.  Gauntlet thrown.  Or is it snowball, in this case?

Comment: Not to mention, that if I can't have a [tag:Dutch] or [tag:Indonesia] tags to bolster my heritage, then no one can have anything!

Comment: Dibs on the first gold badge for [tag:anglo-saxon-bitzer]

Comment: I was wating for this question after I saw a question with just [tag:canada] ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.l-way.com/no-canada.gif

this tag has been burninated.

Comment: *applause* <pad>

Comment: Blame [tag:canada]! Blame [tag:canada]!

Comment: Shouldn't this question now have the `status-completed` tag? Apart from throwing a few jokes around there doesn't seem to be a lot more to discuss on the topic.

Comment: Your image link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

I feel it falls into the "can't stand alone" definition of a meta tag, and as such should die in a fire (or a snowdrift, if that's your preference).  Also, I can't think of a situation where it'd make sense to use it that wouldn't fall foul of our dislike for either "too localized" or else "shopping question".

Comment: This was my feeling as well

Answer (score 4):

I would have liked the CANADA tag to be retained - it's appropriate for questions pertaining to IT in Igloos, or hazards facing consultants travelling to sites where moose or polar bears are common.

Comment: I bet the costs associated with A/C are quite nice in igloos

Comment: Yes, but dehumidifying cost are what kill.